# O que fazer para não perdermos conteúdo potencialmente importante

Tags: debate

Hoje me deparei com o seguinte cenário: Um usuário, que possivelmente estava descontente por algum motivo, alterou todas as respostas que já havia dado para a seguinte mensagem:

> Estou apagando minha conta e todas as minhas perguntas e respostas.

A pergunta é: Não perderíamos conteúdo, já que muitas das respostas foram marcadas como corretas e tem muitas visualizações / upvotes? O que poderíamos fazer neste caso, pensando que talvez estas respostas sejam realmente de propriedade deste usuário e não do site?

Imagens sobre o ocorrido abaixo:

[image: Imagem 1]
[image: Imagem 2]

Comment: Tinha acabado de publicar a respeito :P http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5833/usu%C3%A1rio-editando-todas-suas-respostas

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Vou marcar essa como duplicada

Comment: Meu entendimento é que a partir do momento que o usuário publicou a resposta, ele deu o consentimento para que o conteúdo fosse da rede, não sei se é o caso de reverter tudo. Ai que entra o debate

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio concordo com você, só não sei se, da maneira como aconteceu, é reversível

Comment: Como assim, "da maneira como aconteceu?" rs

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio o cara já editou e excluiu tudo, não sei se dá pra reverter agora que o estrago já tá feito hehe

Comment: Ve la, teve duas respostas dele(que tinham gratificações) que eu reverti, dei um Rollback... o problema é que não sei se temos essa autoridade, ainda mais quando o usuário claramente quis apagar o conteúdo de autoria dele, mas acho que não tem problema não... acho rs

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio na real acho que só um admin pra dizer pra gente. Eu particularmente acho que dá pra banir o cara e manter as respostas hahaha Mas isso baseado em achismo pessoal

Comment: Aproveitei e fiz rollback em todas edições dele.